# How can I corrupt a table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2005, corruption

I have to write a program that detects corrupted tables and tries to repair them. For this I need to corrupt tables regularly.

Is there anyway to corrupt tables manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paul Randal has several [Sample corrupt databases to play with](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Conference-corruption-demo-scripts-and-example-corrupt-databases.aspx):

- **DemoDataPurity** -  192-MB SQL Server 2005 database with a single 2570 (data purity) error
- **DemoFatalCorruption1** -  1-MB SQL Server 2005 database with a corrupt system table (that allows CHECKDB to complete)
- **DemoFatalCorruption2** - 1-MB SQL Server 2005 database with a corrupt system table (that terminates CHECKDB)
- **DemoNCIndex** - 192-MB SQL Server 2005 database with a bunch of nonclustered index corruptions
- **DemoRestoreOrRepair** - 1-MB SQL Server 2005 database with a page checksum failure (in fact a zero'd out page)
- **DemoCorruptMetadata** - 1-MB SQL Server *2000* database with corrupt syscolumns table

Also, [How to create a corrupt database using BULK INSERT/ UPDATE and BCP - SQL Server as a HEX editor.](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/tonyrogerson/archive/2007/03/10/how-to-create-a-corrupt-database-using-bulk-insert-update-and-bcp-sql-server-as-a-hex-editor.aspx)

Comment: Paul thanks for the database collection, but for testing i will be using our database. Thus i we need the tables of my database to be corrupt. Is there anyway to corrupt tables manually?

Comment: @Karthick M Mayan: Sure is. Read that last linked article I posted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually know what makes a table corrupt, but since you'll be scanning for certain symptoms, you know that, right? So you could just open the database file in, say, a hex editor and modify the corresponding data, e.g. change a value representing the number of records to come or something like that?

Comment: thanks Nicolas for the suggestion. will try something of his sort.